# How to check for identical strings in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

How can I check if a list contains identical strings in python? I have tried searching for something like this on previous stack exchange questions, and I can't seem to find example what I'm looking for. I am currently writing a simple poem generation program based on conditional frequency distribution. Occasionally, the program will return a line with several words in repetition.
For example:

"winter is it is" "rain fell today is it is" and "meet cuckoo when i would i"

If something like this occurs, I want to tell my computer to regenerate the line until a new line is made that does not have this problem. I have found ways to get rid of the same word appearing twice in a row (such as "the the") and problems when entire lines are repetitions (such as "is it is it is), but for some reason lines with some repetition still get by.

Here's my code that checks for whether a line should be regenerated or not.

```
                       for item in lineN:
                        if lineN.count(item) > 1: 
                            #Regens line if 2 words repeat infinitely. Ex: "it is it is it"
                            break
                        elif any(lineN[i]==lineN[i+1] for i in range(len(lineN)-1)): 
                            #Regens line if same word appears twice in a row. Ex: "the the"
                            break
                        else: 
                            #Poem is correct and will be returned from function
                            return lineN, strN
                            break
```

How can I search if there are identical strings in a list?

Comment: Use `Collection.counter()` and check if any of the counts are more than 1.

Comment: Why don't you fix the generator so it doesn't produce duplicate words in the first place?

Comment: `len(my_list)` > `len(set(my_list))` will be `true` if any items are repeated. (Though use `Collection.counter()` as suggested if you need to know *which* words are duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment, here is your code.

```py
for item in lineN: 
    if len(lineN) != len(set(lineN)):
        break
    elif lineN.count(item) > 1: #Regens line if 2 words repeat infinitely. Ex: "it is it is it" 
        break 
    elif any(lineN[i]==lineN[i+1]:
        for i in range(len(lineN)-1)): #Regens line if same word appears twice in a row. Ex: "the the" 
             break 
    else: #Poem is correct and will be returned from function 
         return lineN, strN break
```

Based on your post, the first conditions should be enought.